Manage API name conflicts between managed package and subscriber org
I am the develeper of a managed package.
Recently, I made changes where I created a new custom field with the API name Country__c.
After creating a new package version, we had a problem.
One of the subcribers had already created a field with the same API name in the same object.
I couldn't simply go back and remove the field, because of this: (Delete Components from managed packages)

When a component is deleted, its Name remains within Salesforce, and you can’t create a new component that uses the deleted component’s name.

Ultimately, we had to ask the Subscriber's developer to rename their field, which is highly inconvenient.
What am I doing wrong here? How do I stop this from happening again?

Can you post exact error you are facing? Subscriber org having same field name will not cause an issue. let say you create a field Name and subscriber also created a field name. But Manage package field name will have API name like prefix__Name__c and subscriber field have api name Name__c. So same field names will not cause an issue.

@ManjotSingh,
That was good point. After looking into it, it turns out we had the same namespace as well, which was a mistake on our part.

The feature your looking for is custom namespaces. Similar to how in Apex you could create a variable named Account and still access the standard Object via Schema.Account, you can use a custom namespace to avoid collisions.
Official Documentation
